# Automating Listing Addresses and Balances Using PHP

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, php

I want to incorporate a javascript in php that list all the accounts and shows balances for those. This is my script for that:

```
<script language="javascript">
function checkAllBalances() {

var totalBal = 0;


for (var acctNum in eth.accounts) {

    var acct = eth.accounts[acctNum];

    var acctBal = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(acct), "ether");

    totalBal += parseFloat(acctBal);

    console.log("  eth.accounts[" + acctNum + "]: \t" + acct + " \tbalance: " + acctBal + " ether");

    alert("eth.accounts[" + acctNum + "]: ");

}

console.log("  Total balance: " + totalBal + " ether");
}</script>
```

I incorporated this into php and and call it but it's not executing it properly. Any ideas?

Comment: If I wasn't clear, I wanted this script to run in geth console. My educated guess would be that javascript doesn't recognize eth. when it is being run inside php without some kind of library being imported, but I don't know how to do that either

Comment: I'm confused what this has to do with PHP. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I am attempting to write a php code that uses this inside so I can use it sort of like an api.

Comment: How on earth do you expect the javascript that comes via PHP to your Browser to run inside a geth console?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple done in PHP using [digitaldonkey/ethereum-php](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php) library

```
$eth = new Ethereum('http://127.0.0.1:7545');
$balanceInWei = $eth->eth_getBalance(new EthD20($address), new EthBlockParam())->val();
$inEther = $eth->convertCurrency($balanceInWei);
```

See: https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php/blob/master/public/list-balance-example.php